# overwritePermissions not functioning

Tags: discord.js

I was trying to make a join to create bot but the over write permissions part did not work. I want the person who "created" the channel to have permission to change the channel's name instead of having the default "username"'s Room name.

```
}
  })
    async function jointocreatechannel(user) {
      console.log(" :: " + user.member.user.username + "#" + user.member.user.discriminator + " :: Created a Room")
      await user.guild.channels.create(`${user.member.user.username}'s Room`, {
        type: 'voice',
        parent: user.channel.parent.id, //or set it as a category id
      }).then(async vc => {
        user.setChannel(vc);
        jointocreatemap.set(`tempvoicechannel_${vc.guild.id}_${vc.id}`, vc.id);
        await vc.overwritePermissions([
          {
            id: user.id,
            allow: ['MANAGE_CHANNELS'],
          },
          {
            id: user.guild.id,
            allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
          },
        ]);
      })
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your discord.js version? What is `user`?

Comment: user is the one who joins the set vc at that time and it's discord.js version 3.2

Answer (score 0):

Please state your discord.js version.
If you are using version 13, then the "overwritePermissions" is not a function

you can use this code to edit the channel permissions

```js
await vc.permissionOverwrites.edit(role, {

    'MANAGE_CHANNELS': true

}).catch((err) => err);
```

although you can do that, I would rather create the permissions when you create the channel. This is the best way in my opinion unless you want to edit the permissions after the user has done something.

This is how you create the permissions

```js
await user.guild.channels.create(`${user.member.user.username}'s Room`, {

    type: 'GUILD_VOICE',
    parent: user.channel.parent.id,
    permissionOverwrites: [

        {

            id: user.id,
            allow: ['MANAGE_CHANNELS']

        },
        {

            id: user.guild.id,
            allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL']

        }

    ]

});
```

Comment: thanks for the help! and i'm sorry that i'm a new to discord.js but i believe that my discord.js is on  "discord.js": "^12.5.3",